# Npx not found when runing pre-commit husky script

Tags: npx, husky, git-husky

#### Environment

- Node installed in `~/node-v14.15.3-linux-x64/bin/node` and already setup in the `PATH` variable.
- VSCode 1.55.2

#### Problem

every time when i try to commit the changes in my code i get:

> .husky/pre-commit: 4: npx: not found
> husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)

#### Code

- husky.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$husky_skip_init" ]; then
  debug () {
    [ "$HUSKY_DEBUG" = "1" ] && echo "husky (debug) - $1"
  }

  readonly hook_name="$(basename "$0")"
  debug "starting $hook_name..."

  if [ "$HUSKY" = "0" ]; then
    debug "HUSKY env variable is set to 0, skipping hook"
    exit 0
  fi

  if [ -f ~/.huskyrc ]; then
    debug "sourcing ~/.huskyrc"
    . ~/.huskyrc
  fi

  export readonly husky_skip_init=1
  sh -e "$0" "$@"
  exitCode="$?"

  if [ $exitCode != 0 ]; then
    echo "husky - $hook_name hook exited with code $exitCode (error)"
    exit $exitCode
  fi

  exit 0
fi
```

- pre-commit file

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
npx lint-staged
```

#### What i tried

- adding this `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,` in `settings.json`
- exporting node & npx in `.huskyrc` like so:

```
export NODEJS_HOME="$HOME/node-v14.15.3-linux-x64/bin"
export NPX_Dir="$HOME/node-v14.15.3-linux-x64/bin/npx"
```

But none worked

> **Note**
> when commiting the changes from the terminal of vscode using `git commit`, the pre-commit script runs normally.

The docs states that:

> You can echo $PATH in your terminal and configure your app to use the same value.

So, How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this problem recently. This error '.husky/pre-commit: 4: npx: not found husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)' was because I had not installed node on my system. I suggest trying this https://www.newline.co/@Adele/how-to-install-nodejs-and-npm-on-macos--22782681

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30523566)

Answer (score 0):

My `.zshrc` contained

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin:$PATH"
```

which adds add my node to my PATH as a part of the zsh configuration process.

So I just copied and placed the same line into a `.huskyrc` file

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.huskyrc
```